# Python supervisord error: <class 'ConnectionRefusedError'>

Tags: python, django, celery, supervisord

I am trying to run my celery tasks in background using supervisor. I foolowed this [article](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2014/05/18/setting-up-an-asynchronous-task-queue-for-django-using-celery-redis/) to setup celery and supervisor.

However when I try to run below command :

```
sudo supervisorctl reread
```

I am getting following error :

```
error: <class 'ConnectionRefusedError'>, [Errno 111] Connection refused: file: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/supervisor/xmlrpc.py line: 560
```

**Conf file**

```
[program:my-app-celery]

command=path_to_project/venv/bin/celery --app=my_app.celery:app worker --loglevel=INFO
environment=PATH="/path_to_project/venv/bin:%(ENV_PATH)s"
directory=/path_to_project/
user=abcuser
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/path_to_project/log/celery-worker.log
stderr_logfile==/path_to_project/log/celery-worker.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10

; Need to wait for currently executing tasks to finish at shutdown.
; Increase this if you have very long running tasks.
stopwaitsecs = 600

; When resorting to send SIGKILL to the program to terminate it
; send SIGKILL to its whole process group instead,
; taking care of its children as well.
killasgroup=true

; if rabbitmq is supervised, set its priority higher
; so it starts first
priority=998
```

**My environment details :**

```
Python 3.6.5

Django 1.11 (In a virtual environment)

supervisord --version
4.0.4
```

Comment: can you paste your supervisor config snippet?

Comment: I ghave updated the question woth conf file